# verifying calls to indexed properties in a dictionary

Tags: c#, dictionary, dependency-injection, mocking, moq

I am trying to mock a class that contains a dictionary, and verify calls to specific indexes of the dictionary.

The interface to the class looks like:

```
public interface IClassWithADictionary
{
    IDictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; }
}
```

And the class looks like:

```
public class ConcreteClassWithADictionary : IClassWithADictionary
{
    public ConcreteClassWithADictionary(IDictionary<string, string> dictionary)
    {
        Dictionary = dictionary;
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Dictionary { get; }
}
```

Now here's where I don't understand, I have a test case where I am attempting to **verify** that a particular key in the dictionary has been set, and later I am attempting to **verify** that this key has been retrieved.

```
[Test]
public void MyTest()
{
    var concreteClassWithADictionaryMock = new Mock<IClassWithADictionary>();

    var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>();

    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock
        .Setup(m => m.Dictionary)
        .Returns(dictionary); // Setting up mock to return a concrete dictionary

    var key = "Key";
    var value = "Value";

    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.Object.Dictionary[key] = value; // Setting the value
    var test = concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.Object.Dictionary[key]; // Getting the value

    // Passes here - no index specified
    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.Verify(m => m.Dictionary);

    // Passes here - with VerifyGet() too
    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.VerifyGet(m => m.Dictionary);

    // Fails here - throws exception, "Expression is not a property access: m => m.Dictionary[.key]"
    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.VerifyGet(m => m.Dictionary[key]);

    //Fails here - no invocation performed, doesn't seem to like the set or the key indexer
    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.VerifySet(m => m.Dictionary[key] = value);

    // Fails here - no invocation performed, even with verifying index access of some kind
    concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.Verify(m => m.Dictionary[key]);
}
```

Clearly the Moq Framework is okay with verifying the getting and setting of the dictionary itself, but not the particular key or index. My question is; what is the proper way to verify the getting and setting of specific keys in a dictionary within a mocked class?

Comment: You are using an actual dictionary and not a mocked one so Moq has no knowledge about the dictionary's members that were accessed.

Comment: I assume the example code snippet provided is for demonstration purposes only as one should not be mocking the subject under test.

Comment: It sure is, apologies, I should have clarified that the test case is not fully representative of my scenario, and it's just an example to explain my misunderstanding :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny I didnt notice it earlier, but that was late night. Basically, it's what Cameron said: You should mock the IDictionary. Here's why:

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // <---- HEEERE

concreteClassWithADictionaryMock
    .Setup(m => m.Dictionary)
    .Returns(dictionary); // Setting up mock to return a concrete dictionary

// ...

concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.Verify(m => m.Dictionary); // A

concreteClassWithADictionaryMock.VerifyGet(m => m.Dictionary[key]); // B
```

Mock does not share information between them.
Furthermore, Mocks are not viruses. They don't infect other classes to inject extra functionality.
Furthermore, Mocks are not a profiler. They don't alter the runtime to inject extra functionality.

That makes Mocks that are not clairvoyant: they see only what was done on them, and have no idea what happened **around them**.

Now we can get to the point: for Verify to work, something **has to record the method calls**. Method calls happen on objects. Object that get the call knows about it. Runtime knows about it. Potential profiler knows about it. And no one else.

First of all, what calls and objects did we really have here?

```
mConcrete.Dictionary[key] :
1)  mock    get_Dictionary  (property getter)
2)  dict    get_Item        (aka. this[])
```

Next, what performs the recording? No the normal typical classes of course. It's all the Mocks that do the recording.

```
mConcrete.Dictionary[key] :
1)  mock    get_Dictionary  (property getter)    <-- 'm' records the call
                                                     and returns dict
                                                     according to setup
```

and then

```
mConcrete.Dictionary[key] :
1)  ...
2)  dict    get_Item        (aka. this[])       <-- plain Dict returns item
                                                    no recording happens
```

Now, when you do Verify, verify can verify anything related to 'm', but when you start 'drilling down' into `m.Dict[]` it hits a wall since the Dictionary is dumb, did not record anything, and even worse - it's not a Mock so it does not even respond to expected recording-related interfaces.

How to fix that? Do a proper setup and mock **as much as you can**. Mock the IDictionary instead of using the plain one.

```
var mDictionary = new Mock<IDictionary<string, string>>();
mDictionary.Setup(d => d["key"]).Returns("value");

var mConcrete = new Mock<IClassWithADictionary>();
mConcrete
    .Setup(m => m.Dictionary)
    .Returns(mDictionary.Object); // Setting up mock to return a mock

var test = mConcrete.Object.Dictionary[key]; // Getting the value

// verify if the Dictionary-Itself was read
mConcrete.Verify(m => m.Dictionary);

// verify if the Dictionary-Contents was read
mDictionary.Verify(m => m.Dictionary["key"]);
```

Note that in the last one, I'm verifying on the dictionary mock. That's because mConcrete **still has no idea** what happened on any other object except for itself.

Last point of interest here: Moq actually supports creating "mock object graphs" on the fly. From [Moq Quickstart](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart):

```
// Make an automatic recursive mock: a mock that will return a new mock for every member that doesn't have an expectation and whose return value can be mocked (i.e. it is not a value type)

// default DefaultValue is DefaultValue.Empty, i.e. NULL of ref types
// let's change that

var mock = new Mock<IFoo> { DefaultValue = DefaultValue.Mock };

// this property access would normally return a NULL
// but now returns a mock of Bar
Bar value = mock.Object.Bar;

// the returned mock is reused, so further accesses to the property return 
// the same mock instance. this allows us to also use this instance to 
// set further expectations on it if we want
var barMock = Mock.Get(value);
barMock.Setup(b => b.Submit()).Returns(true);
```

If you have 'nested' interfaces, like here - IConcreteClass that returns IDictionary (it does return IDictionary instead of Dictionary, right?:) ) then you may use this feature to have the IDictionary mock (and any inner) created automatically by Moq.

Answer (score -1):

The answer is somewhat trivial.

You should mock the dictionary returned by the mock class, and call the verify methods on that instead.